# OpenVZ tells me: hostname: the specified hostname is invalid on boot of the VE

Tags: debian, hostname, openvz, proxmox

I’m using Proxmox 2.1, which is based on Debian 6, for my OpenVZ installation. Which shouldn’t matter but I wanted to mention it before I begin with my problem.

I imported several VEs into my newly set up Proxmox 2.1 installation. All the old hostnames were preserved, they work as expected.

But, when I set up a new VE using the Proxmox UI and set a hostname for them the hostname doesn’t show up in the VE. It shows the host’s hostname at the bash prompt. (user@host-hostname instead of user@ve-hostname)

When I restart the VE using the OpenVZ CLI tools, I get the following error:

`hostname: the specified hostname is invalid`

The `/etc/hosts`and the `/etc/hostname` do show the content I expected, the hostname is set properly.

When executing `hostname -f` inside the VZ I get the following error:

`hostname: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. I was using underscores in my hostnames which isn't allowed. My bad.